# awk - Print output between quotes

Tags: shell, awk

how can I print the result of awk inside double quotes?
like this:

```sh
du Screenshot*.png | awk '{print $2}'
```

result that I get:

```sh
Screenshot_20200404_180903.png
Screenshot_20200404_181044.png
Screenshot_20200404_181057.png
Screenshot_20200404_181116.png
```

result that I want:

```sh
"Screenshot_20200404_180903.png"
"Screenshot_20200404_181044.png"
"Screenshot_20200404_181057.png"
"Screenshot_20200404_181116.png"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```sh
ls Screenshot*.png | awk '{print "\""$2"\""}'
```

Explanation:

AWK `print` statement output the following arguments that are:
variables content (e.g. `$foo` if you have a variable named "foo",
`$2` for the second field of current record...) and litterals
(i.e. strings and numbers...) and some special symbols like coma
(to insert the output field separator.) Note that the arguments
can/should have space between them (for better readability) but
are concatenated in the output (hence the need to put delimitors
with coma or space string.)
AWK strings are within double quotes, and can contain escaped
characters with backslash. That's usefull to output tabulation
(`\t`) and double quote itself (`\"`) Hence the strange notation
above.